# Can't type in React input text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying my first bit of React.js and am stumped early on... I have the code below, which renders a search form into `<div id="search"></div>`. But typing in the search box does nothing.

Presumably something is going missing passing the props and state up and down, and this seems like a common problem. But I'm stumped - I can't see what's missing.

```
var SearchFacet = React.createClass({
  handleChange: function() {
    this.props.onUserInput(
      this.refs.searchStringInput.value
    )
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        Search for:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.props.searchString}
          ref="searchStringInput"
          onchange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var SearchTool = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form>
        <SearchFacet 
          searchString={this.props.searchString}
          onUserInput={this.props.onUserInput}
         />
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
});

var Searcher = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      searchString: ''
    }
  },

  handleUserInput: function(searchString) {
    this.setState({
      searchString: searchString
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchTool 
          searchString={this.state.searchString}
          onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Searcher />,
  document.getElementById('searcher')
);
```

(Eventually I will have other types of `SearchFacet*` but I'm just trying to get this one working.)

Comment: Try logging `this` when you input the text field. It could be that `this` is not the `Searcher` component anymore.

Comment: Thanks FaureHu - logging `this` at which point in the code? Trying to log from `Searcher.handleUserInput()` or `SearchFacet.handleChange()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: you can see my answer for similar questions. You can find detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713718/input-field-doesnt-receive-keyboard-events-when-rendering-with-value-property/36871399?noredirect=1#comment61310144_36871399

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You haven't properly cased your `onchange` prop in the `input`. It needs to be `onChange` in JSX.

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={this.props.searchString}
  ref="searchStringInput"
  onchange={this.handleChange} <--[should be onChange]
/>
```

The topic of passing a `value` prop to an `<input>`, and then somehow changing the value passed in response to user interaction using an `onChange` handler is pretty well-considered [in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

They refer to such inputs as [Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), and refer to inputs that instead let the DOM natively handle the input's value and subsequent changes from the user as [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

Whenever you set the `value` prop of an `input` to some variable, **you have a Controlled Component**. This means you *must* change the value of the variable by some programmatic means or else the input will always hold that value and will never change, even when you type -- the native behaviour of the input, to update its value on typing, is *overridden* by React here.

So, you're correctly taking that variable from state, and have a handler to update the state all set up fine. The problem was because you have `onchange` and not the correct `onChange` the handler was never being called and so the `value` was never being updated when you type into the input. When you do use `onChange` the handler *is* called, the `value` *is* updated when you type, and you see your changes.

Answer (score 272):

Using `value={whatever}` will make it so you cannot type in the input field. You should use `defaultValue="Hello!"`.

See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Also, the `onchange` should be `onChange` as @davnicwil points out.

Comment: In my requirement  i wanted to input field with typing enable as well as it needs to be set to default value came from a state variable. defaultValue attribute was fine but there is a problem in updating default value according to state changes, is there some way to force default value to change?

Comment: You should post that issue as another question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @GeoffreyHale I'm not quite sure what you mean by how it is misleading. See this example that doesn't use state: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQJZwr?editors=0010. Or this one that does: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbMJMX?editors=0010

Comment: @Ivan You are right, both are immutable: `value={whatever}` and  `value={this.state.myvalue}`. I should have made *this clarification* instead: using `onChange={this.handleChange}` and anything like `handleChange: function(e) {
        var newState = {};
        newState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(newState);
    },` makes fields mutable again.

Comment: @ivan, maybe update your answer to say `defaultValue={whatever}` can be used. It's not the fact that it's not straight text, it's the fact that using `value` makes it immutable but you can assign anything to `defaultValue` and still be able to edit it after the fact

Comment: When using Formik validation, I think it's necessary to use ```value```, no? Could you have a look here? onChange doesn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689720/onchange-on-textinput-not-working-inside-formik

Answer (score 26):

For me the following simple change worked perfectly

```
<input type="text" 
        value={props.letter} 
        onChange={event => setTxtLetter(event.target.value)} /> {/* does not work */}
```

> change... value={myPropVal} to... defaultValue={myPropVal}

```
<input type="text" 
        defaultValue={props.letter} 
        onChange={event => setTxtLetter(event.target.value)} /> {/* Works!! */}
```

Comment: I think onChange doesn't work properly when used within Formik. I was trying this too but it didn't work for me. Could you please have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689720/onchange-on-textinput-not-working-inside-formik

Answer (score 12):

This might be caused by the onChange function is not updating the proper value which is mentioned in the input.

Example:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.textValue} onChange = {this.changeText}></input>

 changeText(event){
        this.setState(
            {textValue : event.target.value}
        );
    }
```

in the onChange function update the mentioned value field.

Comment: where to define this changeText func?

Comment: If it's a stateless component, inside the function, and if it's a class component, inside the constructor.

Comment: you don't need to write this.state inside the setState. If you only write textValue : event.target.value inside setState , It also work perfectly

Answer (score 6):

Instead of value use defaultValue

We use value when the fields are empty, but if we have to type or update the value from the value already in the input box. We must use defaultValue

Answer (score 4):

I also have same problem and in my case I injected reducer properly but still I couldn't type in field. It turns out if you are using `immutable` you have to use `redux-form/immutable`.

```
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form/immutable';
const reducer = combineReducers{

    form: formReducer
}
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form/immutable';
/* your component */
```

Notice that your state should be like `state->form` otherwise you have to explicitly config the library also the name for state should be `form`.
see this [issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2379)

Answer (score 1):

In a class component context...

#### If the changeHandler method is a normal function:

```js
handleChange(e){
    this.setState({[e.target.name]:[e.target.value]});
}
```

it can be used such as this...`onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)}`

```js
<input type="text" name="any" value={this.state.any} onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)}></input>
```

#### If the changeHandler method is an arrow function:

```js
handle = (e) =>{
        this.setState({[e.target.name]:[e.target.value]});
    }
```

it can be used like this... `onChange={this.handle}`

```js
 <input type="text" name="any2" value={this.state.any2} onChange={this.handle} ></input>
```

And this solved my "Can't type in React input text field" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give the onChange to the searchTool.

Answer (score 0):

Once I ran into a similar error. Let me describe it.

*Edit.js*

```
   // components returns edit form 
   
   function EditVideo({id}) {
   .....
   
   // onChange event listener 
    const handleChange = (e) => {
       setTextData({
           ...textData,
           [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim()
        });
     }
  
   ....
   ...
   }
)
```

*ImportEdit.js*

```
   import Edit from './Edit';
   
    function ImportEdit() {
    ......
     ...
    return (
        <div>
            <EditVideo id={id}/>
        </div>
       )
    }

    export default ImportEdit
```

*The Problem was:*  **I was unable to use spacebar (i.e. if i press spacekey, i didn't see space input)**

*The Bug:* **.trim()**

.trim() method was trimming all the white space i typed

*Note:* Edit.js worked fine when used sepeartely without import

Answer (score 0):

In my case i use Material ui and also needed `name="data"`  (same as state)

```
 <TextField name="fecha" id="fecha" label="fecha"  value={this.state.fecha} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

the **name value** is needed for react works

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem, i fixed it by adding a `value` and a `name` params to each input i used.

Here an example:

```
const onValueChange = (e) => {
    setProduct({ ...product, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}
//...
<input
      type="number"
      id="exampleFormControlInput4"
      label="Price :"
      placeholder="Enter price"
      text="Must be a number"
      aria-describedby="exampleFormControlInputHelpInline"
      onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
      value={price}
      name="price"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your input field names. I corrected my input field names and issue solved for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33634506)