# Not able to enter value on input field onChange prop

Tags: reactjs

I'm unable to input a value on the input field when selecting edit, i think it could be a onChange issue.

I look at something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006333/cant-type-in-react-input-text-field), but the code seems to be outdated, and im using controlled components and not refs.

[image]

[image]

**Editable.js** this component renders an input field when edit is clicked

```
import React from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const Editable = (props) => (
    <div>
        <TextField
            id="outlined-name"
            label="Title"
            style={{width: 560}}
            name="title"
            value={props.editField}
            onChange={props.onChange}
            margin="normal"
            variant="outlined"/>

    </div>
)

export default Editable;
```

**PostList.js** renders a list of the post items

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DeletePost} from '../actions/';
import Editable from './Editable';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
        }
    }
    // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each
     // time the Component rerenders.
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // maybe their is issue with it calling title from name in the editable 
        // component
        this.setState({
            [e.target.title]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    render(){
        const {posts, editForm, isEditing} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {posts.map((post, i) => (
                    <Paper key={i} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                        <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                        {/* if else teneray operator */}
                        {isEditing ? (
                             <Editable editField={post.title} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                        ): (
                            <div>
                                {post.title}
                            </div>    
                        )}         
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography component="p">
                            {post.post_content}
                            <h5>
                                by: {post.username}</h5>
                            <Typography color="textSecondary">{moment(post.createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                        </Typography>
                        {!isEditing ? (
                            <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm}>
                                Edit
                            </Button>
                        ):(
                            <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm}>
                                Update
                            </Button>
                        )}
                        <Button
                            variant="outlined"
                            color="primary"
                            type="submit"
                            onClick={this.removePost(post.id)}>
                            Remove
                        </Button>
                    </Paper>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

**Posts.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PostList from './PostList';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {GetPosts} from '../actions/';
const Styles = {
    myPaper:{
      margin: '20px 0px',
      padding:'20px'
    }
    , 
    wrapper:{
      padding:'0px 60px'
    }
}
class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    loading: true,
    isEditing: false, 
  }
  async componentWillMount(){
    await this.props.GetPosts();
    this.setState({ loading: false })
    const reduxPosts = this.props.myPosts;
    const ourPosts = reduxPosts  
    console.log(reduxPosts); // shows posts line 35
  }

  formEditing = () => {

    if(this.state.isEditing){
      this.setState({
        isEditing: false
      });
    }

    else{
      this.setState({
        isEditing:true
      })
    }
  }


  render() {
    const {loading} = this.state;
    const { myPosts} = this.props
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (<Redirect to='/signIn' />);
    }
    if(loading){
      return "loading..."
    }
    return (
      <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
        <h1> Posts </h1>
        <PostList  isEditing={this.state.isEditing} editForm={this.formEditing} posts={myPosts}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
  myPosts: state.post.posts
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, state) => ({
  GetPosts: () => dispatch( GetPosts())
});
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Posts));
```

Comment: You're setting the value for your input from `props.title` but your `onChange` is affecting your state.  That disconnect means you will not be able to change the value of that input, since you can't edit a components own props.  Consider where the source of truth is for your `posts`, add that to state, and then your `onChange` should edit that in the state.

Comment: in layman terms please, im sorry.

Comment: You're setting the value of your input from a different place than where you are trying to edit it.

Comment: what should i do though ?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the value of the input with the property `this.props.posts[index].title` but you're handling the change through the `PostList`s state.

You should either delegate the `onChange` function to the component that's passing the list to your `PostList` component or store and update the list through the `PostList`s state.

Comment: i just updated the code, what do you think i should do now ?

Comment: `Posts` owns the list so it should pass `onChange` function to the `PostList` function:

` <PostList  isEditing={this.state.isEditing} editForm={this.formEditing} posts={myPosts} onChange={/* function that updates the state here */}/>`

and in the `PostList` component:

`<Editable editField={post.title} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>`

As a general rule, the component who keeps the value/list should be the one that handle any changes relating to the data.

Comment: thanks, even though i really don't understand. I will figure this out. thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the value being set in change function

```
onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // maybe their is issue with it calling title from name in the editable 
    // component
    this.setState({
        [e.target.title]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

youre setting the state of your edit field. You have to reference that value again when you reference your Editable.

```
<Editable editField={this.state.[here should be whatever e.target.title was for editable change event] } onChange={this.onChange}/>
```

in your editable component your setting the value to the prop editField.

```
 <TextField
            id="outlined-name"
            label="Title"
            style={{width: 560}}
            name="title"
            **value={props.editField}**
            onChange={props.onChange}
            margin="normal"
            variant="outlined"/>
```

hope that helps

Comment: This is pretty much the same code, this doesn't really help it just confuses me ever more. Thank you for your feedback, however im still confused on what to do.

Comment: <TextField
            value={props.editField}
           />
you just need to pass the value you want to display back to value

Comment: i would need {post.title} though. Not state. thats the thing

Comment: the value you're passing back to TextField will be from your state. Your setting the value you want to pass back in your onChange call.

Comment: How would i keep the {post.title} in tac. I want to be able to make it editable you know what i mean.

Comment: Then have a post.title and a post.editTitle initially set editTitle to title