# React functional component onChange problem

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and try to create a simple integer input field that allows only numbers to enter.

My code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";


export const IntegerInput = props => {

    const maxLength = props.maxLength ? parseInt(props.maxLength) : 10;

    const [intValue, setIntValue] = useState(props.value);

    const inputMask = new RegExp(/^[0-9\b]+$/);

    function handleChange(e) {
        let inputValue = e.target.value;

        let isNumber = inputMask.test(inputValue);
        let isEmpty = inputValue === '';

        if (isEmpty || isNumber) {
            console.log('Update value to: ' + inputValue);
            setIntValue(inputValue);
        } else {
            console.log('Invalid input: ' + inputValue);
        }

    }

    return (
        <input name = {props.name}
               id = {props.name + '-id'}
               type = "text"
               className = {props.className}
               maxLength = {maxLength}
               value = {intValue}
               onChange = {handleChange}
        />
    );

}
```

There is no error in the console and `setIntValue` is called only if needed but still can enter any character in the input field.

What could be the problem?

Please note, that I want to use "text" input and not "number" and I have the problem on the React side and not with the JavaScript.

Comment: change type="number"

Comment: As the question was mistakenly closed, I write the solution here. The problem was that value was not present in the props so the component become uncontrolled. This post helped me: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006333/cant-type-in-react-input-text-field)

Answer (score 0):

Ciao try to modify your input type like this:

```
    <input name = {props.name}
           id = {props.name + '-id'}
           type = "number"
           className = {props.className}
           maxLength = {maxLength}
           value = {intValue}
           onChange = {handleChange}
    />
```

This should solve your problem.