# Syntax error: Unexpected token by using firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am now following [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7T48W0cwXM) to develop an Instagram clone app by using React with firebase.

The error occurred at the point below, on the video at 2:36:29.

It says "Syntax error: Unexpected token (93:12)"

```
{user?.displayName ? (
    <ImageUpload username={user.displayName} />
  ) : (
    <h3>sorry you need to login to upload</h3>
  )}
```

[image]

what I tried

・Just put `<ImageUpload username={user.displayName} />`

=> I got 「firebase is not defined」 error on the other js file.

・put `"user.displayName"` instead of `"user?.displayName"` (? is erased)

[image]

=> more complicated error occur that "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'displayName')"

[image]

・Put　`{user ? (<ImageUpload username={user.displayName} />) : (<h3>Sorry you need to login !!</h3>)}`　eraced `displayName`

=> only visual works(surely, the username is not given in this case)

Adobe three tries, I guess displayName is the main point to solve the issue...

If you are good at React.js or you have seen the same error, please give me advice.

Whole App.js codes↓

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import { db, auth } from './firebase';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Input from '@mui/material/Input';
//import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import ImageUpload from './ImageUpload';

const style = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  border: '2px solid #000',
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [openSignIn, setOpenSignIn] = useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        //User has logged IN
        console.log(authUser);
        setUser(authUser);
        //↑ is keep user logged in after refresh
      } else {
        //User has logged OUT
        setUser(null);
      }
    })

    return () => {
      //perform some cleanup actions
      unsubscribe(null);
    }
  }, [user, username]);

  //useEffect => where the code runs, last []) means the code runs only once
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        post: doc.data()
      })));
    })
  }, []);

  //signup func
  const signup = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((authUser) => {
        return authUser.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: username
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));

    setOpen(false);
  }

  //signin func
  const signin = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));

    setOpenSignIn(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {user.displayName ? (
        <ImageUpload username={user.displayName} />
      ) : (
        <h3>sorry you need to login to upload</h3>
      )}


      <div className="app__header">
        <img
          className="app__headerImage"
          src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png"
          alt="HeaderImage"
        />
        {user ? (
          <Button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Logout</Button>
        ) : (
          <div className="app__loginContainer">
            <Button onClick={() => setOpenSignIn(true)}>SignIn</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>SignUp</Button>
          </div>
        )}

      </div>

      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <form className="app__signup">
            <center>
              <img
                className="app__headerImage"
                src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png"
                alt="HeaderImage"
              />
            </center>
            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="username"
              //at first, ↓ was value={username}, but typing cannot be shown on the screen in that case,
              //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006333/cant-type-in-react-input-text-field
              //↑is the trouble shooting, which says try defaultValue instead of value(V is capital).
              defaultValue={username}
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="email"
              defaultValue={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="password"
              defaultValue={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <center>
              <Button type="submit" onClick={signup}>SignUp</Button>
            </center>
          </form>

        </Box>
      </Modal>

      <Modal
        //signupModal
        open={openSignIn}
        onClose={() => setOpenSignIn(false)}
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <form className="app__signup">
            <center>
              <img
                className="app__headerImage"
                src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png"
                alt="HeaderImage"
              />
            </center>

            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="email"
              defaultValue={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="password"
              defaultValue={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <center>
              <Button type="submit" onClick={signin}>SignIn</Button>
            </center>
          </form>

        </Box>
      </Modal>
      <h1>TEST</h1>
      {/* header */}
      {
        posts.map(({ id, post }) => (
          <Post username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl} />
        ))
      }

      {/* post */}
      {/* post */}
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here↓ is ImageUpload.js which I got firebase is not defined when I erase the? mark from ImageUpload tag,,,,

firebase is not defined from this line↓

```
timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```

ImageUpload.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { storage, db } from "./firebase";
import firebase from 'firebase/app';


function ImageUpload(username) {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [caption, setCaption] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      setImage(e.target.files[0])
    }
  };

  const handleUpload = () => {
    const uploadTask = storage.ref('images/${image.name}').put(image);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_change",
      (snapshot) => {
        //progress function
        const progress = Math.round(
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        );
        setProgress(progress);
      },
      (error) => {
        //error function
        console.log(error);
        alert(error.message);
      },
      () => {
        //complete func
        storage
          .ref("images")
          .child(image.name)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then(url => {
            //post image inside DB
            db.collection("posts").add({
              timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              caption: caption,
              imageUrl: url,
              username: username
            });

            setProgress(0);
            setCaption("");
            setImage(null);
          })
      }
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {/* I want to have .... */}
      {/* caption input */}
      {/* file picker */}
      {/* Post button */}

      <progress value={progress} max="100" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter a caption.." onChange={event => setCaption(event.target.value)} />
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
      <Button onClick={handleUpload}>
        upload
      </Button>
    </div >
  )
}

export default ImageUpload
```

To be safe here ↓ is firebase.js(privacy info are shown as ***)

firebase.js

```js
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "*****",
  appId: "****",
  measurementId: "****"
})

const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { db, auth, storage };
```

And index.js

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Moreover, firebase version is 8.10.0, using MacBook air intel one OS BigSur

Comment: Are you in an environment that asupports the null-safe operator? `firebase` being undefined is a separate issue, and there’s no code here that uses it.

Comment: It seems user is null. Can you share the code of the other js file in which you get firebase is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I add the ImageUpload.js below. I also thought that firebase is a separate issue, it worked with warnings at least.